# Update a relationship via REST API

Tags: rest-api

I've got an `Account` object on which I've created a multiple relationship `Online_quotes1__r` that accepts `OnlineQuote__c` objects. Now I'd like to relate my `OnlineQuote__c` objects with `Account` via REST API.

Trying to do it via:

PATCH:`/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Account/[id]/Online_quotes1__r` endpoint gives me `HTTP Method 'PATCH' not allowed. Allowed are HEAD,GET` error

And via:
PATCH:`'/services/data/v42.0/sobjects/Account/[id]/'` endpoint gives me `QueryResult must start with '{'` error for payload:

```
'Online_quotes1__r' => [

 ]
```

and `Invalid field in QueryResult: 'Id'` for payload:

```
'Online_quotes1__r' => [
    'Id' => '[id]'
]
```

What is the syntax to do what I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom relationship name on a parent object, here `Online_quotes1__r`, is used in SOQL to query from the parent down the child and in Apex to access queried child objects. You cannot, however, write to the custom relationship as a field in order to add new child objects.

Instead, you can manipulate the children directly. Here's an example with Contact and Account (where the relationship name is `Contacts`, but the mechanism works the same way).

```
GET /services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Account/0013600001sxEUmAAM/Contacts
```

> { "totalSize" : 1, "done" : true, "records" : [ { "attributes" : { "type" : "Contact", "url" : "/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Contact/0033600001qwBXEAA2" }, "Id" : "0033600001qwBXEAA2", "IsDeleted" : false, "MasterRecordId" : null, "AccountId" : "0013600001sxEUmAAM", "LastName" : "Testerson", "FirstName" : "Test", ... }

So that gets me a list of *currently associated* child objects, including their Ids. Suppose though that I have a Contact (this one, `0033600001qwBXEAA2`, that doesn't have a parent Account or that needs to be reparented. In that situation, I do

```
PATCH /services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Contact/0033600001qwBXEAA2
Body: { "AccountId": "YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID_HERE" }
```

Rather than touching the relationship name, I simply supply the lookup field on the child object.

Or, to create a new child, I do

```
POST /services/data/v43.0/sobjects/Contact/
Body: { "AccountId": "0013600001sxEUmAAM", "FirstName": "Tom", "LastName": "Test" }
```

And then I get back a response that includes the Id of the new child.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for custom objects (or my setup, idk tbh) - if I'll try to update my `OnlineQuote__c` object with PATCH: `{"AccountID": [id]}` I get `"No such column 'AccountId' on sobject of type OnlineQuote__c"`. Inside SF CRM I do however have a Online Quote tab for `Account` object

Comment: The relationship field on `OnlineQuote__c` will not be `AccountId`; since it's a custom field, it will certainly end in `__c`. You need to examine your data model to determine what the API name of that custom lookup field is.

Comment: Yup - that's it; I've `RelatedAccount__c` but either I was looking at wrong object or stopping my population of relationships midprocess as it didn't feed to CRM in the Online Quote tab. After your enquiry I've retested it and indeed it works as expected.